# Как поменять nginx.conf чтобы сайт отображался корректно

Tags: nginx, docker

my nginx.conf:

```
   events {

    worker_connections  80;

   }

http {
  index    index.html index.htm index.php;


  server {
    listen       80;

    location / {
       autoindex on;
       autoindex_exact_size on;
    }
  }

}
```

my dockerfile:

```
FROM node:alpine as builder

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
ENV CI=1
COPY . .
RUN yarn

RUN npm run-script build


FROM nginx:alpine
RUN rm -rf /etc/nginx/html/*
COPY --from=builder ./app/_site /etc/nginx/html


COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какие есть ошибки в консоли разоработчика браузера? В логах Nginx? И похоже вы приложили не тот конфиг, который используется в Nginx. Как минимум я не вижу директивы root